# ignore some nodes while reading json tree using jackson

Tags: java, android, json, performance, jackson

I have to improve performances while reading a json from an URL using Jackson.
The solution is to ignore some nodes unneeded for the treatment after, and I'm not seeing how?

To be more specific This methods take 1,4 seconds on AVG, cause it explores all nodes and sometimes only one is needed (genre in the url example).

```
public static JsonNode readFromURL() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException,        MalformedURLException, IOException
{
    return mapper.readValue(new URL("http://api.mixotv.com/2/guide/now"), JsonNode.class);
}
```

Thanks.